# Winsock alternative (no, not WinPCAP)

Tags: c++, winsock, packets

Are there any viable alternatives to Winsock for C++? The reason I need of is because Winsock's raw sockets are not behaving properly (no, this is not fixable, don't waste your time asking) and WinPCAP can only monitor network traffic, not actually receive packets. I need something that can receive complete packets including any IP, UDP, TCP headers, etc. Does such a thing exist, and if not, why not?

Comment: I'm going to waste my time asking: Why doesn't it work for you? If you're going to claim that [product that works for everyone else] doesn't work, then you ought to spend a least a sentence or two backing it up.

Comment: It would take too long to explain and would lead to more questions.

Comment: You're right - it typically leads to more questions, and most times (especially when the OP doesn't explain their situation up front) it leads to us discovering that's they not using [product that works for everyone else] correctly. Take nearly every "I think I found a bug in GCC" post, for example. Hence, I ask the time wasting question.

Comment: If your Winsock implementation is actually broken then I'm afraid you're pretty F'd mate. I recommended Boost.Asio, but if WS32 is *really* not working than anything that wraps it will be broken too.

Comment: Actually I will try: using the different parameters to the socket function of winsock  either causes my app to not receive any packets (sock_raw, ipproto_raw), causes all the sockets I have created to receive the same packet (sock_raw, ipproto_udp) or function properly but not receive headers (sock_dgram, ipproto_udp)

Answer (score 6):

> WinPCAP can only monitor network traffic, not actually receive packets

Monitoring network traffic is equivalent to receiving packets. That's exactly what tools such as Wireshark do: read off your network card and reconstruct packet boundaries.

> I need something that can receive complete packets including any IP, UDP, TCP headers, etc.

This is very much possible using the Winsock API. Have a look at the [`WSAIoctl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621%28VS.85%29.aspx) function, specifically the `SIO_RCVALL` option - enabling this option will deliver ALL packets received on an interface to your socket. And these are raw IP packets starting with the IP header.

Comment: No, monitoring traffic is not equivalent to receiving packets because when you monitor, you just observe the conversation of other programs without being able to participate. I do not want to receive all the packets on the network, I just want the ones I would normally get but I want the headers.

Comment: Could you not then write a function that narrows all of the packets down to just the ones you want, and passes those on to the rest of your system?

Comment: @Chroma: Raw packets do not correspond to any application by themselves. It's the port number in the headers that directs them to the right program. So you have two choices: either get all raw packets and filter them yourself, or let the OS do this for you and lose the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). C++ cross-platform IO library. Support for UDP, TCP and ICMP.

Comment: And that allows you to receive the entire packet including all headers and everything?

Comment: Boost.Asio wraps the BSD socket library. Seeing as Winsock can do it (and Winsock is based on BSD sockets too) then Asio can do it. The basic_socket class wraps the `ioctl` function.

Comment: Yes, boost can assure you that the entire packet is received. Look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html